# Alternative to long lines

Tags: sh, ash

Context: I have a script in that long lines are being striped.

In bash, I could do this

```
CURL=/usr/bin/curl

declare -a ARGS=(
  --silent
  --location
  --output /dev/null
  --write-out "%{http_code}"
  --request GET
  --max-time 30
  --retry 3
  "https://httpbin.org/status/200"
)

http_code=$("$CURL" "${ARGS[@]}")
```

However, ash does not have arrays. Is there another alternative to avoid long lines like I can do on bash in `ash` or in `sh`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323535/375565
I think you can use the following

Answer (score 2):

Long lines can be split with backslashes:

```
CURL=/usr/bin/curl

curlWithArgs(){
    "$CURL" \
        --silent \
        --location \
        --output /dev/null \
        --write-out "%{http_code}" \
        --request GET \
        --max-time 30 \
        --retry 3 \
        "https://httpbin.org/status/200" \
        ;
}

http_code=$(curlWithArgs)
```

Comment: Note that this could have problems if some of the arguments contain spaces (which doesn't seem to be an issue in this case).

Comment: @KeithThompson surely, only exactly as many problems as writing the declare command?

Comment: You're right, I didn't read closely enough. The `declare -a` command collects the arguments into a single variable (which is an array, which avoids problems with embedded spaces if you're careful). The `curlWithArgs()` function doesn't do that, and any embedded spaces can just be quoted or escaped.

Comment: But I'd probably use double quotes on that last line: `http_code="$(curlWithArgs)"`

Comment: @KeithThompson I always get confused. It's certainly safe, but is it necessary in assignments? `x=$(printf 'x\t \ta\n\t'); printf '%s' "$x" | od -c`

Comment: Suppose the current directory contains `a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`. Then `echo $(echo '*.c')` prints `a.c b.c c.c`, and `echo "$(echo '*.c')"` prints `*.c`. (Admittedly a contrived example.)

Comment: @KeithThompson you seem to be talking about [command expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) which I agree needs proper quoting; but [assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) don't cause word-splitting or globbing

Comment: I was referring to the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in the last line of your answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson "4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable." / "A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]` [...] All values undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal [...] Word splitting is not performed, with the exception of "$@" as explained below. Filename expansion is not performed."

Comment: @KeithThompson that seems to match the results of printf test I gave - the result of the command substitution when it is part of an assignment seems to be applied as is. "Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted"